# Usability - How to edit favorites?

Tags: usability, editing

I'd like to get some opinions about about usability in 
the following case:

1. Target group people from 30-50, low to middle internet 
   affinity.
2. App: I have a website with login. Visitors can save 
   interesseting pages in their fav-box for fast access.
3. Here the actual question: How to edit this favorites?
   Is it better to give the visitors direct access to 
   drag/dropn and delete their favs or is it better to
   have an edit button so they have to activate the edit
   mode before?
   The fav-link would look like this >

---

| link text to click      | icon-drag | icon-delete |

---

thx for input
TC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For low-middle internet affinity, I'd say KISS. Have a VERY visible and easy to trigger "Edit My Favorite Links List" button.

Not a link - not only is having links for actions is a bad idea in general (see Nielsen and assorted SO link vs button discussions), but for the target audience ease of clicking is even more important.

I would also make the editing mode either a pop-up or a modal sprite (large size) so that the editing functionality elements can be made large and obvious and easy to access.

Comment: @Florian - you're welcome. If you find it useful, feel free to up-vote it, and accept it as accepted answer (that's the big checkmark next to the answer). Cheers.